# How to configure AWS CloudFront with s3 and Lightsail Origin

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-lightsail

I am trying to build a website which satisfies all 3 conditions below.

```
1."https://example.com/"         → Refer to s3 bucket "aaa"
2."https://example.com/service"  → Refer to s3 bucket "aaa" /service directory
3."https://example.com/magazine" → Refer to the Lightsail Wordpress page
```

Now the domain "example.com" is associated with CloudFront "bbb.cloudfront.net" on Route53.
I set the origin for this CloudFront which is s3 bucket "aaa", and the behavior setting is to refer to this s3 bucket by default. With this, condition 1 and 2 can be satisfied easily.

But is there any way to configure condition 3?
Is is possible to set a behavior for "bbb.cloudfront.net" to refer to Lightsail IP address?
I found some ways to achieve this with subdomains, like let https://ccc.example.com/ to refer to Lightsail IP address but subdomain is not what I want.

I'm not sure if this structure (CloudFront + s3 + Lightsail) itself has a problem or if there is a way. Could anyone give me some advice if you have any notices?

Comment: Have you tried adding the lightsail workload as a second Origin in your CF distribution? Then you should be able to add a behaviour (eg. /magazine) for the origin?

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Actually that is the point that I am struggling because the Origin should be a domain name, so Lightsail's IP address or instance name would be inappropriate. Or is there other way to add the Lightsail as an Origin?

Comment: This thread might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53446900/how-to-setup-aws-cloudfront-with-lightsail-for-wordpress - you could create a subdomain that points to your lightsail app, eg. origin.example.com, then use origin.example.com as your origin in CloudFront. Then you could point example.com to CF.

Comment: Again Thank you so much for your comment! Exactly creating a subdomain was the solution and I could do what I wanted ! I will describe more in the answer below.

Answer (score 4):

Thank you so much [JBS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2641696/jbs)!

This issue is solved and I describe what I did below.

Structure image:
[aws lightsail with Cloudfront](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZhII.png)

1. Create a subdomain wp.example.com and register that in Route53 as A record, with Lightsail's IP address. The subdomain name doesn't matter because it will be used only for accessing from Cloudfront.
2. Create a Cloudfront origin with the subdomain above, set Protocol policy to "Redirect HTTP to HTTPS", Allowed HTTP Methods to ALL.
3. In the Cloudfront, refer to this page and create 5 behaviors for the subdomain above. (In my case I added /magazine at the top of each behaviors)
   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/whitepapers/latest/best-practices-wordpress/cloudfront-distribution-creation.html
   Whitelisting "HTTP_CLOUDFRONT_FORWARDED_PROTO" and "HOST" are the key to access wordpress with "example.com" domain. Also it is important to allow all cookies and query strings for Dynamic paths (wp-admin/* and wp-login.php)
4. In the Cloudfront general setting, set CNAME to "example.com"
5. At this point, Javascript and CSS are blocked because they are accessed with HTTP. On the wordpress admin UI, add plugin "SSL Insecure Content Fixer" and in its HTTPS detection setting, select "HTTP_CLOUDFRONT_FORWARDED_PROTO" and save.

this thread was useful too: [Any way to set up AWS Cloudfront to point to static IP address (WP hosted on GoDaddy)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55681184/any-way-to-set-up-aws-cloudfront-to-point-to-static-ip-address-wp-hosted-on-god)

Comment: Glad it worked!